What can cause prometheus' `rate` function to return absurdly high values when the underlying series look normal?
I have a counter series that looks normal when queried directly:
energy_watthours_total{meter="export"}
Response:
{"status":"success",
 "data":
    {"resultType":"matrix",
     "result":
        [{"metric": {"__name__":"energy_watthours_total","instance":"XXX","job":"XXX","meter":"export"},
          "values": [
            [1728564000,"24335660"],
            [1728564014,"24335660"],
            [1728564028,"24335736"],
            [1728564042,"24335730"],
            [1728564056,"24335798"],
            [1728564070,"24335900"],
            [1728564084,"24335960"],
            [1728564098,"24336041"],
            [1728564112,"24336119"],
            [1728564126,"24336175"],
            [1728564140,"24336251"],
            [1728564154,"24336306"],
            [1728564168,"24336380"],
            [1728564182,"24336468"],
            [1728564196,"24336521"]
          ]
        }]
    }
}

But if I ask for its rate:
rate(energy_watthours_total{meter="export"}[1m])
I occasionally get abnormally high values (it happened three times in a year; I had to track down the precise time):
{"status":"success",
 "data":
    {"resultType":"matrix",
     "result":
        [{"metric": {"instance":"XXX","job":"XXX","meter":"export"},
          "values":[
             [1728564000,"3.822222222222222"],
             [1728564014,"3.822222222222222"],
             [1728564028,"4.266666666666666"],
             [1728564042,"540796.8666666666"],
             [1728564056,"540797.2"],
             [1728564070,"540797.7777777778"],
             [1728564084,"5.111111111111111"],
             [1728564098,"5.3999999999999995"],
             [1728564112,"4.866666666666666"],
             [1728564126,"4.777777777777777"],
             [1728564140,"4.666666666666666"],
             [1728564154,"4.155555555555555"],
             [1728564168,"4.555555555555555"],
             [1728564182,"4.822222222222222"],
             [1728564196,"4.777777777777777"]
          ]
      }]
   }
} 

I don't see anything suspect in the TSDB dump either:
$ promtool tsdb dump --min-time=1728564000000 --max-time=1728564196000 --match='energy_watthours_total{meter="export"}'
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.4335736e+07 1728564014395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.433573e+07 1728564029395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.4335798e+07 1728564044395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.43359e+07 1728564059395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.433596e+07 1728564074395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.4336041e+07 1728564089395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.4336119e+07 1728564104395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.4336175e+07 1728564119395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.4336251e+07 1728564134395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.4336306e+07 1728564149395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.433638e+07 1728564164395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.4336468e+07 1728564179395
{__name__="energy_watthours_total", instance="XXX", job="XXX", meter="export"} 2.4336521e+07 1728564194395

The problem affects rate, irate, and increase, but not delta; I presume this is related to counter reset detection, but why does this happen, and how can I avoid that ?

Value at 1728564042 is less than previous value. From counter point of view - it is a reset, with extremely high rate of value increase after reset.

@markalex you are right. I looked at these +"*ç%&/ numbers for half an hour and somehow didn't notice. Thanks.
